# .htaccess rewrite = 404 page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to make for example www.mydomain.com/about.php to www.mydomain.com/about.

Based on some blog reading,

Here what I have on my httpd.conf

```
<Directory "var/www/mydomain">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
Order allow, deny
RewriteEngine On
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess file

```
Order deny,allow
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

www.mydomain.com/about.php still works but the /about has 404 URL Not Found page.

Is there something wrong with the above configuration?

Answer (score 0):

In your last line, try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$     $1.php [L]
```

(note the ^ and the removed R=301)

If it doesn't work, try removing all previous lines in your `.htaccess` file. Only keep `RewriteEngine On` only.

Comment: Not sure if this is a helpful hint or not. When I removed the "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI" line from the httpd.conf, I got "You Don't have permission to access this page" message.

Comment: @hangee Last shot, try removing only `Includes ExecCGI` to see what happens. Also, in my `httpd.conf`, I have the following order (don't know if it's related): 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks / 
AllowOverride All / 
Order allow,deny / 
Allow from all

Comment: @hangee (replace **/** with a new line)

Answer (score 0):

Your first two RewriteRules mandate that there be a / after the name, as the last character. You probably want to make that optional:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/$2.php
```

That may be why you're not matching /about in the first rewrite group. I presume you're trying to do something different in the second rewrite group, but it's not clear what (hint: a comment or two on what you're doing would be quite helpful).